# How to groupby and generate summary table for each course unit using python and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I'm analyzing survey data and I need to generate the summary result sheet for every course unit.

My survey data looks like:

| CourseCode | Unit | Q1contentxxx | Q2contentyyy | Q3contentsss | Q4contentddd | Q5contentfff | Q6contentggg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3300 | 1 | StronglyAgree | Agree | Neutral | StronglyAgree | Agree | Neutral |
| 3300 | 2 | StronglyDisagree | Neutral | Disagree | StronglyDisagree | Neutral | Disagree |
| 3200 | 2 | Agree | Disagree | Neutral | Agree | Disagree | Neutral |
| 3100 | 1 | Agree | Disagree | Neutral | Agree | Disagree | Neutral |
| 3300 | 2 | Disagree | Neutral | Disagree | Disagree | Neutral | Disagree |

The Answer only contains five options--StronglyAgree; Agree; Neutral; Disagree; StronglyDisagree

I would like to generate a summary table for every course unit like:
Course Unit 3300-2:

| Question | StronglyAgree | Agree | Neutral | Disagree | StronglyDisagree |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Q1contentxxx | 0% | 0% | 0% | 50% | 50% |
| Q2contentyyy | 0% | 0% | 100% | 0% | 0% |
| Q3contentsss | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% | 0% |
| Q4contentddd | 0% | 0% | 0% | 50% | 50% |
| Q5contentfff | 0% | 0% | 100% | 0% | 0% |
| Q6contentggg | 0% | 0% | 0% | 100% | 0% |

I was thinking that I should use "while loop" to iterate and print what I need, but I stucked here and I would like to know if there's any better way to groupby the result to show what I want.

```
    i=1;
    while i < 6:
      print(df.loc[i, 'CourseCode':'Unit']);
      print(df.where(...
      i++;
```

Here's an example of what I was thinking, there must be better ideas, so thank you in advance for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step1**

filtering by 3300-2 & melt

```
target = '3300-2'
cond = df['CourseCode'].astype('str').add('-').add(df['Unit'].astype('str')).eq(target)
tmp = df[cond].melt(['CourseCode', 'Unit'])
```

tmp:

```
CourseCode  Unit    variable    value
0   3300    2   Q1contentxxx    StronglyDisagree
1   3300    2   Q1contentxxx    Disagree
2   3300    2   Q2contentyyy    Neutral
3   3300    2   Q2contentyyy    Neutral
4   3300    2   Q3contentsss    Disagree
5   3300    2   Q3contentsss    Disagree
6   3300    2   Q4contentddd    StronglyDisagree
7   3300    2   Q4contentddd    Disagree
8   3300    2   Q5contentfff    Neutral
9   3300    2   Q5contentfff    Neutral
10  3300    2   Q6contentggg    Disagree
11  3300    2   Q6contentggg    Disagree
```

**Step2**

aggregate by `pd.crosstab`

```
cols = ['StronglyAgree', 'Agree', 'Neutral', 'Disagree', 'StronglyDisagree']
tmp2 = pd.crosstab(tmp['variable'], tmp['value']).reindex(cols, axis=1, fill_value=0)

#change to percentage
out = tmp2.div(tmp2.sum(axis=1), axis=0).mul(100).astype('int').astype('str').add('%')\
          .rename_axis('Question').rename_axis('', axis=1).reset_index()
```

out:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Panda Kim, Your answer is fast and perfect as always! It's exactly what I want, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

One possible option :

```
target = "3300-2"

tmp = df.set_index(["CourseCode", "Unit"])
tmp.index = map("{0[0]}-{0[1]}".format, tmp.index)

# cols = np.unique(tmp) or if order matters, you can hardcode the values
cols = ["StronglyAgree", "Agree", "Neutral", "Disagree", "StronglyDisagree"]

out = (
    tmp.loc[[target]].stack().str.get_dummies()
        .groupby(level=1).agg(lambda s: (s.sum())/s.size*100)
        .reindex(cols, axis=1, fill_value=0)
        .reset_index(names=["Question"])
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

       Question  StronglyAgree  Agree  Neutral  Disagree  StronglyDisagree
0  Q1contentxxx              0      0      0.0      50.0              50.0
1  Q2contentyyy              0      0    100.0       0.0               0.0
2  Q3contentsss              0      0      0.0     100.0               0.0
3  Q4contentddd              0      0      0.0      50.0              50.0
4  Q5contentfff              0      0    100.0       0.0               0.0
5  Q6contentggg              0      0      0.0     100.0               0.0
```

Comment: Hi @Timeless, thank you for your answer! That's the result I want!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can use `pd.melt` followed by `groupby` to get your results:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars= ['CourseCode', 'Unit']) # converts from wide to long format
df2 = pd.get_dummies(df['value'])
df = pd.concat([df,df2], axis=1).groupby(['CourseCode', 'Unit', 'variable'])[df2.columns].sum() # gets the count
df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0) # gets the percentage count
```

Output:

|  | Agree | Disagree | Neutral | StronglyAgree | StronglyDisagree |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (3100, 1, 'Q1contentxxx') | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| (3100, 1, 'Q2contentyyy') | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| (3100, 1, 'Q3contentsss') | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| (3100, 1, 'Q4contentddd') | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| (3100, 1, 'Q5contentfff') | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| (3100, 1, 'Q6contentggg') | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| (3200, 2, 'Q1contentxxx') | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| (3200, 2, 'Q2contentyyy') | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| (3200, 2, 'Q3contentsss') | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| (3200, 2, 'Q4contentddd') | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| (3200, 2, 'Q5contentfff') | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| (3200, 2, 'Q6contentggg') | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| (3300, 1, 'Q1contentxxx') | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| (3300, 1, 'Q2contentyyy') | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| (3300, 1, 'Q3contentsss') | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| (3300, 1, 'Q4contentddd') | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| (3300, 1, 'Q5contentfff') | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| (3300, 1, 'Q6contentggg') | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| (3300, 2, 'Q1contentxxx') | 0 | 0.5 | 0 | 0 | 0.5 |
| (3300, 2, 'Q2contentyyy') | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| (3300, 2, 'Q3contentsss') | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| (3300, 2, 'Q4contentddd') | 0 | 0.5 | 0 | 0 | 0.5 |
| (3300, 2, 'Q5contentfff') | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| (3300, 2, 'Q6contentggg') | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```py
out = (
    df.set_index(["CourseCode", "Unit"])
    .stack()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={0: "mood"})
)
out["Course"] = out.pop("CourseCode").astype(str) + "-" + out.pop("Unit").astype(str)

out = (
    out.assign(tmp=1)
    .pivot_table(
        index=["level_2", "Course"],
        columns="mood",
        values="tmp",
        aggfunc=len,
        margins=True,
        fill_value=0,
    )
    .rename_axis(index=[None, None], columns=None)
)
out = out.div(out.iloc[:, -1], axis=0) * 100

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
                     Agree    Disagree     Neutral  StronglyAgree  StronglyDisagree    All
Q1contentxxx 3100-1  100.0    0.000000    0.000000       0.000000          0.000000  100.0
             3200-2  100.0    0.000000    0.000000       0.000000          0.000000  100.0
             3300-1    0.0    0.000000    0.000000     100.000000          0.000000  100.0
             3300-2    0.0   50.000000    0.000000       0.000000         50.000000  100.0
Q2contentyyy 3100-1    0.0  100.000000    0.000000       0.000000          0.000000  100.0
             3200-2    0.0  100.000000    0.000000       0.000000          0.000000  100.0
             3300-1  100.0    0.000000    0.000000       0.000000          0.000000  100.0
             3300-2    0.0    0.000000  100.000000       0.000000          0.000000  100.0
Q3contentsss 3100-1    0.0    0.000000  100.000000       0.000000          0.000000  100.0
             3200-2    0.0    0.000000  100.000000       0.000000          0.000000  100.0
             3300-1    0.0    0.000000  100.000000       0.000000          0.000000  100.0
             3300-2    0.0  100.000000    0.000000       0.000000          0.000000  100.0
Q4contentddd 3100-1  100.0    0.000000    0.000000       0.000000          0.000000  100.0
             3200-2  100.0    0.000000    0.000000       0.000000          0.000000  100.0
             3300-1    0.0    0.000000    0.000000     100.000000          0.000000  100.0
             3300-2    0.0   50.000000    0.000000       0.000000         50.000000  100.0
Q5contentfff 3100-1    0.0  100.000000    0.000000       0.000000          0.000000  100.0
             3200-2    0.0  100.000000    0.000000       0.000000          0.000000  100.0
             3300-1  100.0    0.000000    0.000000       0.000000          0.000000  100.0
             3300-2    0.0    0.000000  100.000000       0.000000          0.000000  100.0
Q6contentggg 3100-1    0.0    0.000000  100.000000       0.000000          0.000000  100.0
             3200-2    0.0    0.000000  100.000000       0.000000          0.000000  100.0
             3300-1    0.0    0.000000  100.000000       0.000000          0.000000  100.0
             3300-2    0.0  100.000000    0.000000       0.000000          0.000000  100.0
All                   20.0   33.333333   33.333333       6.666667          6.666667  100.0
```